# Haskell function that outputs all combinations within the input list that add to the input number

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I want to write a function in haskell that takes a list of integers and an integer value as input and outputs a list of all the lists that contain combinations of elements that add up to the input integer.

For example:

myFunc [3,7,5,9,13,17] 30 = [[13,17],[3,5,9,13]]

Attempt:

```
myFunc :: [Integer] -> Integer -> [[Integer]]
myFunc list sm = case list of
    [] -> []
    [x]
        | x == sm -> [x]
        | otherwise -> []
    (x : xs)
        | x + myFunc xs == sm -> [x] ++ myFunc[xs]
        | otherwise -> myFunc xs
```

My code produces just one combination and that combination must be consecutive, which is not what I want to achieve

Comment: You say repetition is allowed, but you don't include `[3,3,3,7,7,7]` as one of the lists that adds up to 30 in your example. If that's not what you mean by repetition, what *do* you mean?

Comment: I meant that a number can appear in two combinations, for example 13 appears twice in [[13,17],[3,5,9,13]]. I think I shouldn't have said that because it is obvious that we can use a number in two combinations so I will remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a function to create all subsets

```
f [] = [[]]
f (x:xs) = f xs ++ map (x:) (f xs)
```

then use the filter

```
filter ((==30) . sum) $ f [3,7,5,9,13,17]

[[13,17],[3,5,9,13]]
```

as suggested by @Ingo you can prune the list while it's generated, for example

```
f :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> [[a]]
f [] = [[]]
f (x:xs) = f xs ++ (filter ((<=30) . sum) $ map (x:) $ f xs)
```

should work faster than generating all 2^N elements.

Comment: This would be a good base for writing a more efficient function, which cuts the subset building process when the resulting list is already greater than the target result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `subsequences` from `Data.List` to give you every possible combination of values, then filter based on your requirement that they add to 30.

```haskell
myFunc :: [Integer] -> Integer -> [[Integer]]
myFunc list sm =
  filter (\x -> sum x == sm) $ subsequences list
```

Comment: But that is cheating :). I want to do it using just primitive recursion.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to use a right fold:

```
fun :: (Foldable t, Num a, Eq a) => t a -> a -> [[a]]
fun = foldr go $ \a -> if a == 0 then [[]] else []
    where go x f a = f a ++ ((x:) <$> f (a - x))
```

then,

```
\> fun [3,7,5,9,13,17] 30
[[13,17],[3,5,9,13]]

\> fun [3,7,5,9,13,17] 12
[[7,5],[3,9]]
```

An advantage of this approach is that it does *not* create any lists *unless* it adds up to the desired value.
Whereas, an approach based on filtering, will create all the possible sub-sequence lists only to drop most of them during filtering step.

Comment: I'm not totally convinced by your last sentence. You indeed don't create any `[a]` lists, but you do end up creating a linked list of thunks like `(a:) <$> (b:) <$> (c:) <$> ...`, which only get thrown away once `...` is discovered to be an empty list after all. So while as you say, you don't create any lists, you do seem to spend as much time and memory on these thunks as you would on a list anyway.

Comment: @amalloy you can benchmark `fun [1..24] 17` to see it for yourself. with `ghc --make -O2` the `filter ... subsequences` solution is 3 times slower than above right fold approach (ghc 7.10.3)

Comment: Seeing that it's faster can't tell me *why* it's faster. It still seems to me like you are allocating one thunk for each cons that you might or might not do.

Comment: @amalloy no that is not true! in `[1..24]` for all sub-sequences that start with 1 (which are `2^23` many of them) I only create _one single thunk_.

Comment: Aha! Okay, I get it now. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate solution idea: Generate a list of lists that sum up to the target number, i.e.:

```
[30]
[29,1]
[28,2]
[28,1,1]
...
```

and only then filter the ones that could be build from your given list.

Pro: could be much faster, especially if your input list is long and your target number comparatively small, such that the list of list of summands is much smaller than the list of subsets of your input list.

Con: does only work when 0 is not in the game.

Finally, you can it do both ways and write a function that decides which algorthm will be faster given some input list and the target number.